# Matching fields in Entity and in liquibase

Tags: java, liquibase

I am studying a training project - working with databases. It seems to be stated that he is a worker. It has not yet been possible to raise the project completely.
Here is the class description of the entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventories", schema = "inventories")
public class Inventory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "part_num_oem")
    private String partNumOEM;
    @Column(name = "part_num")
    private String partNum;
    @Column(name = "part_name")
    private String partName;
    private String version;
    private Integer year;
    @Column(name = "image_exists")
    private Boolean imageExists;
}
```

And here is the liquibase file of creating the table itself

```
<changeSet id="create_inventories" author="adam">
    <createTable tableName="inventories" schemaName="inventories">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="part_num_oem" type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        <column name="part_num" type="VARCHAR(100)"/>
        <column name="part_name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="version" type="VARCHAR(50)"/>
        <column name="year" type="INT"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

There is no *image_exists* field from the Entity description class in this file.
Isn't that a mistake?
Or is it possible to do this?
When adding a new entity to the database in this case, an error will not pop up?

Shouldn't the Entity Entity file fully match the file for liquibase?

Comment: It is *definitely* a mistake - from the ones that happen in real life. The JPA provider will find out eventually at runtime when trying to access that Entity. You may get it to warn you at deployment time with something like (Hibernate-specific) `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>`. It may be possible to write some kind of integration tests that include the Liquibase scripts. An [example](https://github.com/nikospara/realworld-v2/blob/master/realworld-v2-common/realworld-v2-common-testutils/src/main/java/realworld/test/liquibase/LiquibaseExtension.java) of my own.

Answer (score 1):

There might be the change-set that alters `inventories` table and adds extra column into it. For example the initial version of `Inventory` class didn't contain `image_exists` field, but it was added later. Since Liquibase computes hashes of change-sets it's recommended to add extra `alter`ing change-set instead of modifying the original one.

Hence if there is some later changelist like following, you most probably won't face any troubles:

```
<changeSet id="add_image_exists_column_to_inventories" author="someone" > 
    <addColumn tableName="inventories">
        <column name="image_exists" type="boolean"/>   
    </addColumn>  
</changeSet>
```